# Using Doctrine ORM, is 450ms website response time slow for users?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Getting ready to launch a new platform, which relies solely on DB queries.

The heaviest page, the first page users see handles a bunch of queries, some little more complex queries. I have the "Newsfeed" which is a heavier query:

```
$friends = User::getLogged()->Friends->getPrimaryKeys() ;
$friends[] = User::getLogged()->id ;
$query = $this->createQuery('o')->addSelect('o.*')
->leftJoin('o.Creator u')->leftJoin('u.Avatarimage av')->addSelect('u.*, av.*')->addSelect('u.id, av.*, u.display_name AS creators_display_name')
    ->leftJoin('u.Profiletype t')
    ->leftJoin('t.ProfiletypeTranslation tm WITH tm.translation_id=?', Translation::getForVisitor()->id)->addSelect('tm.name AS creators_profiletype_name')
  // for type: NEW_IMAGES_IN_ALBUM
 ->leftJoin('o.NewImagesInAlbum i WITH i.album_id=o.album_id')->addSelect('i.id, i.filename, i.width, i.height') 
    ->leftJoin('o.Album a')->addSelect('a.id, a.name AS album_name')
// for type: NEW_CASTING 
->leftJoin('o.Casting s')
    ->addSelect('s.*, s.title AS castings_title')
// for type: NEW_COMMENT_ON_IMAGE               
->leftJoin('o.Comment c')
    ->leftJoin('c.User u1')->addSelect('c.*, u1.display_name AS receivers_display_name')
    ->leftJoin('c.Image i2')
    ->leftJoin('i2.Album a2')->addSelect('a2.name AS album_of_commented_image')
// for type: NEW_FRIENDSHIP
->leftJoin('o.NewFriends nf')
    ->leftJoin('nf.Avatarimage nfav')
    ->addSelect('nf.*, nfav.*')
->orderBy('created_at DESC')
->whereIn('o.creator_id', $friends)
->andWhereIn('o.type', array
    (
        Activity::NEW_IMAGES_IN_ALBUM, 
        Activity::NEW_PROFILE_STATUS, 
//                  Activity::NEW_COMMENT_ON_USER, 
        Activity::NEW_COMMENT_ON_IMAGE, 
        Activity::NEW_CASTING, 
        Activity::NEW_FRIENDSHIP, 
        Activity::NEW_AVATAR
    )
    )
//              ->where('type=?', 1)
//              ->groupBy('o.id')
->limit(20) ;
return $query->execute() ;
```

That's the biggest query on the page, there is another big query for finding notifications, and 3 other smaller queries for finding messages, etc...

The page feels like it loads instantly to me, but using Chrome, Chrome shows 452ms waiting (CPU processing all my damn class files), and then another 200ms to deliver/load everything, so in total it's 650ms to show everything.

In the world of user interaction and social networking, is this going to be to slow for users? Do I need to try and optimize even more? I'm running a dual six-cores xeon 2.4ghz (12 cores total). I might have to upgrade to an even faster one to handle all of the users and reduce the time it takes for PHP to load all the class files.

What are your thoughts on 450ms with Doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

A cursory look at your queries shows me that you are using select * for basically every query, that doesn't help a database server with performance.